# What is the difference between InvokeVoidAsync and InvokeAsync JsRuntime?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, interop

What are the differences between these two and which one should I use?

```
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync()
await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync()`
```

Comment: Read the main Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

**InvokeVoidAsync**

Use `InvokeVoidAsync` when:

- .NET isn't required to read the result of a JavaScript (JS) call.
- JS functions return void(0)/void 0 or undefined.

For example the below function can call with `InvokeVoidAsync` and doesn't return a value:

```
<script>
  window.displayTickerAlert1 = (symbol, price) => {
    alert(`${symbol}: $${price}!`);
  };
</script>
```

And you can use this in a component by following code:

```
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("displayTickerAlert1", stockSymbol, price);
```

**InvokeAsync**

Use `InvokeAsync` when .NET should read the result of a JavaScript (JS) call.

The following example returns a string for display by the caller:

```
<script>
  window.displayTickerAlert2 = (symbol, price) => {
    if (price < 20) {
      alert(`${symbol}: $${price}!`);
      return "User alerted in the browser.";
    } else {
      return "User NOT alerted.";
    }
  };
</script>
```

And you can use of this to a component such as below:

```
 var interopResult = 
            await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("displayTickerAlert2", stockSymbol, price);
        result = $"Result of TickerChanged call for {stockSymbol} at " +
            $"{price.ToString("c")}: {interopResult}";
```

Please note that you have to inject `IJSRuntime` on the above of the component, such as below:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
```

You can refer to [Calling JavaScript from .NET](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/) and [call-javascript-from-dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync() executes Javascript function and this function do not return any value to C# code

await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync() also execute Javascript function but can return some value to C# code